# Find no of swaps needed to club identical elements of array together

Tags: java, algorithm, edit-distance

I have created a solution for the problem as below:

> Given a string S consisting of letters 'O' and 'Z'. Calculate the
>   minimum number of changes required such that all O's are adjacent to
>   each other and all Z's are adjacent to each other. One change is
>   equivalent to swapping two neighbouring letters
>
> for e.g for a given array: oozozo  desired array is : oooozz so,min no
>   of swap would be 3,which should be the desired output.

Let me know if the solution has any bad practices.

My Code:

```
package com.test.practice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String numberOfInputs = br.readLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs.length(); i++) {
            String inputString = br.readLine();

            findNumberOfTurns(inputString);
        }

    }

    private static void findNumberOfTurns(String inputString) {

        int count = 0;
        char[] input = inputString.toCharArray();
        char firstCharacter = input[0];
        char secondCharacter;
        boolean secondCharEncountered = false;
        int countSecondChar = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (firstCharacter == input[i]) {
                if (!secondCharEncountered) {
                    countSecondChar=0;
                } else {
                    count+=countSecondChar;
                    secondCharEncountered=false;
                }
            } else {
                secondCharEncountered=true;
                countSecondChar+=1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bug**

Your method doesn't calculate the correct number of swaps. Using the input string `oozzoo` the correct result should be **`4`** but your algorithm gets a result of **`2`**.

**Single resopsonsibility principle**

The `findNumberOfTurns()` method is calculating the number of swaps **and** prints the output which is too much. Let the method return the number of swaps needed. Printing the result shouldn't be in that method.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. It helped rectify the problem.Will keep the single responsibility principle in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to get the logic of your code...
Here is my approach.

Suppose you want to group all O's at the beginning and all Z's at the end. Then each O needs that many swaps, what is its offset from its final position: if the first O is at the third place, it needs 2 swaps; if the second O is at the seventh place, it needs 5 swaps; and so on. So the number of swaps needed to move all O's to the left can be calculated as:

```
    int numberOfOSwapsL = 0;
    int numberOfOs      = 0;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < input.length; pos++) {
        if (input[pos] == 'o') {
            numberOfOSwapsL += pos - numberOfOs;
            numberOfOs ++;
        }
    }
```

But you might also try to move all O's to the right. We would need to swap each O with each Z to move all O's from left to the right, which makes `numberOfOs * (input.length - numberOfOs)` swaps. If you subtract those swaps needed to shift O's to the left, you get the number of swaps needed to move them to the right *from the initial configuration*:

```
    int numberOfOSwapsR = numberOfOs * (input.length - numberOfOs) - numberOfOSwapsL;
```

Finally the minimum number of swaps needed to group O's together and Z's together is the smaller one from `numberOfOSwapsL` and `numberOfOSwapsR`.